# boostrap div inside a container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to place a navigation inside the main container in bootsrap but when I put it inside the main container I can't even click on the navigation as if it was another element on top of it.

[image]

```
<div class="container" id="faqe1">


   <div class="dotstyle dotstyle-tooltip">

                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>   




    </div> <!-- Kontaineri -->
```

I tried

```
z-index
```

but no joy!

Any help?

**EDITED**

heres the navigation's css

```
.dotstyle ul {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    top:25em;
    left: -8em;

    transform: rotate(90deg)


}

.dotstyle li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 16px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;




}

.dotstyle li a {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    text-indent: -999em; /* make the text accessible to screen readers */
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;





}

.dotstyle li a:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* Individual styles and effects */



/* Tooltip */

.dotstyle-tooltip li {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;
    transition: border-color 0.3s ease;






}

.dotstyle-tooltip li a {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 250%;
    left: 50%;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #c44d48;
    color: #fff;
    text-indent: 0;
    line-height: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, visibility 0s 0.3s ease;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, visibility 0s 0.3s ease;




}

.dotstyle-tooltip li a::after { /* http: //cssarrowplease.com/ */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: #c44d48;
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 99%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;


}

.no-touch .dotstyle-tooltip li:hover a,
.dotstyle-tooltip li.current a {
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;




}

.dotstyle-tooltip li.current {
    border-color: #c44d48;
}

.dotstyle-tooltip li:hover {
    z-index: 100;
}

.no-touch .dotstyle-tooltip ul:hover li.current a {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.dotstyle-tooltip ul li.current:hover a {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

and i also have this for the containers background and gradient overlay:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}


#faqe1 {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image:url("../images/Unknown-2.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;


}


#faqe1:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -9999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( rgba(255,155,245,.8) 0%,rgba(0,155,0,.6) 100%);
}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean ?  it works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17618/

Comment: Do you have the CSS that goes along with that?  Dev site link, etc.

Comment: question edited, note that its not a bootstrap default navigation. its a normal div. but when i put it out of the container it works but theres a gap on top of the page. i want it to stay inside the boostrap container but when i put it inside i cant click or hover over it etc, simply like there is smthng above it so thats why i thought its a z-index thing but it doesent work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z-index on the #faqe1 is the one that's causing the problem, when you get rid of it you should be able to access the links. See the link below for this:

## faqe1 {

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image:url("../images/Unknown-2.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
```

}

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXdNoY)

Comment: great!!! @VinceBinamira :) when u have a lot of z-indexes u mess the things up and thats why stackoverflow is here. thank u guys.